# Does type of a critical point depend on domain?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Suppose we have a function $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$, for a domain $D$, and $X \in D$ is a saddle point of $f$.

Is it possible that if we constrain $f$ to a new domain $C$, where $C \subset D$, the same $X \in C$ becomes a local minimum instead of a saddle point of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually domains are defined to be open sets, in which case you'd always have a ball around your saddle point, keeping it a saddle point. If you allow for closed sets, then yes it's possible by slicing the saddle point to only include an increasing or decreasing piece of it.

Comment: I was particularly looking at $D = \{X | X  \text{ is a } t \times t \text{ matrix , }  rank(X) \le k\}$, $C = \{X| X \text{ is a  } t \times t \text{ matrix, } rank(x) \le k-1 \}$

Comment: @user25004: and what's $f$?

Comment: $f$ is a quit general real function of a matrix. Not fixed.

Comment: Is this domain closed or open?

Comment: Intuitively, any matrix with rank exactly $k$ can be broken to one with rank $>k$ by slightly pushing one of the dependent vectors. So the set is not open. It should on the other hand be closed, as one cannot have a limiting matrix to be rank $>k$ without having at least one $>k$ rank matrix in the sequence.